# EPS File Text Image Adobe Illistruator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, text, images

I am just wondering if there is a way to easily edit this text.

It appears to be an image??

[image: screenshot of text/image in Illustrator with layers and groups]

Answer (score 4):

No easy way as far I know. You have to rewrite with the text tool, try to find a similar font of the image.
Use this website to find the font (or get similar types)  https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Answer (score 2):

It depends if you are trying to "re-write" or edit in another way. It IS an image, and it's possible to do an **Image Trace** if you just want to change some things. Keep in mind, once you do this, each letter will be an individual object, not an editable letter. However, you could always use a similar font to supplement... there are several options depending on what you're trying to change.

*I'm assuming you aren't stealing this logo from someone else and just want to change some things for yourself...*

If I were you, I would:

1. `Window`> `image trace`
2. Play around with the settings after selecting the **Black & White Logo** preset until the image looks right:

[image]

3. **Expand** in the top middle of the menu bar.

Here's a more extensive guide to **Image Tracing**: http://blogs.adobe.com/adobeillustrator/2013/07/image-trace-in-illustrator-a-tutorial-and-guide.html

*edit: I can't see your layers, but perhaps this is already done?? I guess we would just need to see more info on what you want to accomplish :)